# Run commands remotely with two levels of indirection

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I need to run a script on a machine that is only accessible by doing ssh to an intermediate bastion machine.

So what I would normally do is

From my local machine:

```
ssh user@bastion
ssh user2@internal-ip
cd work/path
./run_my_script
```

I woud like to either write a script that, at the end, runs the script in work/path in the machine identified by internal-ip. The script should be run from my local machine.

How can I accomplish this? Assume that all key exchanges have been made and hence all ssh interactions are passwordless.

Answer (score 0):

If you use OpenSSH you can use `ProxyJump` directive in .ssh/config or an equivalent `-J` command line option to handle the `ssh user@bastion` part. It would be:

```
ssh -J user@bastion user2@internal-ip "cd work/path && ./run_my_script"
```

Comment: Would have been awsome if it had worked. I'm not sure what the problem is but I got a "channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535"

Comment: I don't know, maybe one of your servers has .profile that prints something to the screen?